# PHP application which worked in XAMPP is not working in IIS 7

Tags: php, iis

Recently I've uploaded my PHP application, which was working in XAMPP into a new server having  IIS7. And now the application stopped working. The login page doesn't authenticate the users.
I followed all the instructions available in the following links,
http://php.iis.net/
http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php
on how to install PHP in IIS and hosting a PHP application in IIS7 using FastCGI but of no result.

What is the problem? I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Have you checked the error logs yet?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: NO errors are shown even-though I kept display_errors= On .